# Print quality of text is lower when vector graphics embedded in page

Tags: pdf, printing, latex

I am generating PDF files from Latex and embed graphics with includegraphics command: these can be bitmap images (PNG, JPEG) or vector graphics (PDF generated from e.g. inkscape or mathematical plotting software as gnuplot). I have an issue with some pages in the same document having a lesser print quality than others: the text is pixellated. This happens on pages where vector graphics are included, but not on pages where bitmap images are included.

What is the reason for this? Is there a workaround (other than convert my vector graphics to bitmap before embedding it in PDF!)

Comment: Is this an issue only when printing or is it also visible in a viewer like Adobe Reader?

Comment: Only when printing.

Comment: Then tell us more about your OS, your printer, your printer driver... - this is not specific to LaTeX.

Comment: While I'm not the OP, I experience this same issue.  I have this issue on two different Ubuntu machines.  One prints to a commercial-grade laser color printer.  The other prints to a home laser black and white printer.  I haven't tried printing on other OS's to see whether it makes a difference.  I'd be interested to know whether printers have any intrinsic memory limitations that might cause this or whether it's more likely a driver and/or OS problem.

Comment: OS: Linux debian ; printers range from Konica-Minolta Bizhub series of printer-copiers down to small HP, Samsung and Konica-Minolta laser printers. Proprietary linux drivers and generic postscript do the same.